# How to trigger a job if the currently running job repeatedly fails?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We currently use the plugin [Downstream Ext Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/downstream-ext/) to create a post-build action to trigger another build if the currently running build fails (to notify support staff).

However, for some builds, I would like to alter the setup so that the other build is triggered **only** when the currently running build has failed for a second time (we have another plugin that manages the auto retry).

These specific builds, for one reason or another, occasionally fail because of a loss of connection etc so there is no need to trigger the other build that notifies support.

Something like,

- Projects to build: ABC
- Build result is **equal** to **REPEATED FAILURE**

I have tried googling but so far have had no luck?

Comment: You could look at using the [Conditional Build Step plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/conditional-buildstep/)

Comment: did you try out the post build task with the status as `Stable` or `Unstable`

Comment: @IanW I haven't so far as was looking for post-build actions and thought this was only available in the build step. Thanks for the tip, will investigate ...

Comment: @Saravanan post-build task is set as Projects to build: ... Build result is **equal** **FAILURE** (i.e. I selected FAILURE from SUCCESS / UNSTABLE / FAILURE / ABORTED).

Comment: @sam-gilbert, you could try flip the logic and have the failure always call the other job, with it having a condition that the evaluates the callee and does nothing unless repeatedly fail. Would need groovy to process the logic tho.

Comment: if you need to know the continuously failing, you can choose unstable state. However for more detailed operations like # of failures, you will have to write groovy script and then process the post build stage